# What is the benefit of using "is" keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

What is the difference below? I sometimes see `is` keyword in typescript but could not figure out the benefit using `arg is string` in this case. Looked up but not much information about it. Could someone explain?

```
const isString = (arg: any): arg is string  => typeof arg === "string";  

const isString = (arg: any) => typeof arg === "string";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). It means that when calling `isString` TypeScript knows to narrow down the type to `string` if it returns `true`.

An example:

```js
declare const foo: string | number;
if (isString(foo)) {
    console.log(foo.toLowerCase());
}
```

If the function doesn't define a custom type guard, the type inside the if block would still be `string | number` and calling `toLowerCase()` would produce an error.

With the type guard, the compiler narrows down the type to `string` inside the if block.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAylATnMBzA6nKALAFQE8AHAUwHEBXAQxQBMYBeGACjowC4YawiBKbh3gQY0NJmYA+GFFJkQAMx4oMzJiwBE49Bk0BuGDACwAKFCRYCZBOy48IKlGLlqdRi3aqhfftNnySipqGlo6mAZmZvRkwAA2dGQwFtAwiiAg3OFqAD4wYFQAtgBGZCj6UaZwyqzWqLo4+C6UtAys6SD8fgDeZkZGKSBxZAB0cSAY7RkjUCAAMiAA7mUAwjQQZKxdFaYAvpXVbHW2jQ5OzW5tHV0wvab9yeAQQ6Pjkx0z80ur65vbZrsgA)

Comment: I know its some time this was answered, but thanks a lot for this.  I was trying to figure out what the advantage of a custom type guard over a simple function, but your example helped a lot.